# Bind properties FromForm .NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have .NET Core Web API project. One of my action controller is:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Notify([FromForm] NotifyInput input)
{ ... }
```

`NotifyInput.cs` file is in separate project (.NET Standard):

```
public string BodyPlain { get; set; }

public string BodyHtml { get; set; }

public List<Attachment> Attachments { get; set; }

public class Attachment
{
    public int Size { get; set; }

    public string Url { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string ContentType { get; set; }
}
```

And params I send to this method are:

```
body-plain: 123
body-html: <p>123</p>
attachments: [{"url": "http://example.com", "content-type": "image/jpeg", "name": "pexels-photo.jpg", "size": 62169}]
```

I'm trying to send my data via Postman as **x-www-form-urlencoded** and as **form-data**.

But when I debug this code, I see they are all `NULL`.

Attribute `[JsonProperty("body-plain")]` didn't help me.

How can I bind these params?

Comment: How are you sending these values to the API?

Comment: Updated question

Comment: I think @DavidG meant specifically *how* are you sending them, like via Postman? What does the *actual* request body look like?

Comment: Off the bat, what you're passing for `attachments` won't work at all. If you're going `x-www-form-urlencoded`, you've got to go all the way, which means having separate params for each property of each attachment, i.e. `attachments[0].Url`, `attachments[0].ContentType`, etc.

Comment: Okay, `attachments[0].url` works fine, but what about `body-html` or `attachments[0].content-type`?

Comment: You need to correspond the fieds to your `NotifyInput` model.So you do not need to use `-` for the key since your model fields do not have short horizontal connector.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [ModelBinder(Name="name")] to specify a name for binding data

```
public class NotifyInput
{
    [ModelBinder(Name = "body-plain")]
    public string BodyPlain { get; set; }
    [ModelBinder(Name = "body-html")]
    public string BodyHtml { get; set; }

    public List<Attachment> Attachments { get; set; }
}
public class Attachment
{
    public int Size { get; set; }

    public string Url { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ModelBinder(Name = "content-type")]
    public string ContentType { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: My class `NotifyInput` is in separate project (.NET Standard) so I can't use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` namespace here.

Answer (score 0):

I played around with this and discovered that because you're passing a `x-www-form-urlencoded` to the endpoint, setting `[JsonProperty("body-plain")]` won't work; because you aren't sending Json.

So to pass those values you have to use the exact names on the models (case insensitive, but no hyphens). So, passing the following

```
bodyplain:123
bodyhtml:<p>123</p>
```

should work. `attachments[0].content-type` also has to become `attachments[0].ContentType`

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't change param names.